# Reading image files into Tensorflow with tf.WholeFileReader()

Tags: python-3.x, file-io, tensorflow

I'm trying to read a directory of images files into tensorflow and I'm having a little trouble. When I run the script, the shell is just hanging (even waited 10 mins for an output) and the only output I get is the from the `print(len(os.listdir())` line

My attempts stem from this guide:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/reading_data

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\Moondra\Desktop\Testing')
print(len(os.listdir()))  # only 2 in this case

file_names =tf.constant(os.listdir(), tf.string)
file_tensors =tf.train.string_input_producer(string_tensor = file_names)
reader =tf.WholeFileReader()
key, value = reader.read(file_tensors)
##features = tf.parse_single_example(value)
#records = reader.num_records_produced()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    values =sess.run(value)
    ##print(records_num)
    print(type(values))
```

The reader is supposed to read images one at a time, so I'm assuming
value will hold the image values on on the current image. 
Despite this, the shell is just hanging and no output.

Thank you  and --just incase @mrry is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.train.string_input_producer` adds a `QueueRunner` to the current Graph and you need to manually start it. Otherwise it is just hanging and no output is produced.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
  threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
  values = sess.run(value)
  # ....
```